# How to fix This browser or app may not be secure. Python selenium

Tags: selenium

I made selenium script to log in into google account but i am getting This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

print('Enter the gmailid and password')
gmailId, passWord = map(str, input().split())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(r'https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue='+\
'https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1'+\
'&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry = ServiceLogin')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

loginBox = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id ="identifierId"]')
loginBox.send_keys(gmailId)

nextButton = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//*[@id ="identifierNext"]')
nextButton[0].click()

passWordBox = driver.find_element("xpath",
    '//*[@id ="password"]/div[1]/div / div[1]/input')
passWordBox.send_keys(passWord)

nextButton = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//*[@id ="passwordNext"]')
nextButton[0].click()

print('Login Successful...!!')
```

Comment: Google checks for bots.  You should look into using their API.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this code to solve it**

[Installing Undetected Selenium](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class Main:
  def __init_(self) -> None:
    self.url    = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin'
    self.driver = driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
    self.time   = 10
    
  def login(self, email, password):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'identifier'))).send_keys(f'{email}\n)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys(f'{password}\n)
                                                                                
    self.code()
                                                                                  
  def code(self):
    # [ ---------- paste your code here ---------- ]
    time.sleep(self.time)                                                                                  
                                                                                  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  #  ---------- EDIT ----------
  email = 'email' # replace email
  password = 'password' # replace password
  #  ---------- EDIT ----------                                                                                                                                                         
 
  driver = Main()
  driver.login(email, password)
```

[Code](https://github.com/xtekky/google-login-bypass/blob/main/login.py)

[For more details you can watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcTGurNyf6Y&ab_channel=xtekky)

Comment: It is not working